# Color table row by status

Tags: php, html-table

I wanna do `if` in   by my status field.
if my status is "blocked" so the font background color will be in red and if the status is "authorized" so in green.

how should i do that?

```
    foreach($data as $row)
   {
    $output .= '
    <tr>

     <td>'.$row->client_name.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->adrress.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->occupation.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->payeee.'</td> 
     <td>'.$row->status.'</td> 


    </tr>
    ';
   }
```

Comment: First of all, to use `@if` you need to be writing code in a .blade template file. This code seems to be standard PHP code somewhere else. Even so, normally you could just do `<tr style="background-color: '.(ternary condition).'">` have you tried something like that and if so can you share what you are having trouble with?

Comment: you right but here it's in my controller.
do u know how can i do IF there?

Comment: I highly recommend  reading a PHP tutorial. The simple thing would be `if (condition) { $output .= ....; } else { $output .= ...; }` and have a different output for each case. This might result in a bit of code duplication but it's a first step and with some more practice and reading you can write a more optimised code.

Comment: TNX U very much it work in the end:)!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code that worked

```
foreach($data as $row){
$output .= '
<tr>

 <td>'.$row->client_name.'</td>
 <td>'.$row->adrress.'</td>
 <td>'.$row->occupation.'</td>
 <td>'.$row->payeee.'</td>';
 if($row->status == "bad"){
    $output .= '<td style="background-color:red;">'.$row->status.'</td>';
 } else if($row->status == "good") {
   $output .= '<td style="background-color:green;">'.$row->status.'</td>';
}
$output .= '</tr>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
$output .= '
<tr>

 <td>'.$row->client_name.'</td>
 <td>'.$row->adrress.'</td>
 <td>'.$row->occupation.'</td>
 <td>'.$row->payeee.'</td> 
   @if($row->status == "blocked")
   <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">blocked</button> </td>
   @elseif($row->status == "authorized")
   <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">authorized</button> </td>
   @endif
 </tr>
```

**OR**

```
foreach($data as $row){
    $output .= '
    <tr>

     <td>'.$row->client_name.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->adrress.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->occupation.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->payeee.'</td>';
     if($row->status == "bad"){
        $output .= '<td style="background-color:red;">'.$row->status.'</td>';
     } else if($row->status == "good") {
       $output .= '<td style="background-color:green;">'.$row->status.'</td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work
I tried it too but it opened another column for me and didn't check the value itself

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you so please give update this anser thank you @Itmar Ben Oren

Comment: Can you please give update this answer thank you@Itamar Ben Ore

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be dealing with view logic in your controller.

But to do what you want in the controller

```
foreach($data as $row){
    $output .= '
    <tr>

     <td>'.$row->client_name.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->adrress.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->occupation.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->payeee.'</td>';
     if($row->status == "bad"){
        $output .= '<td style="background-color:red;">'.$row->status.'</td>';
     } else if($row->status == "good") {
       $output .= '<td style="background-color:green;">'.$row->status.'</td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

However what you should do is handle it in your blade file.  Also you probably want to create styles in your style sheet and apply classes rather than inline the css.